# How to remove NoData tags from Tiff?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a Tiff:

```
D:\10000>gdalinfo 10000_EPSG2536_2.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 10000_EPSG2536_2.tif
Size is 58954, 54068
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",..]
Origin = (1450324.596294234700000,438752.955720250490000)
Pixel Size = (1.037488337128723,-1.037488337128723)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1450324.596,  438752.956) 
Lower Left  ( 1450324.596,  382658.036) 
Upper Right ( 1511488.684,  438752.956)
Lower Right ( 1511488.684,  382658.036)
Center      ( 1480906.640,  410705.496) 
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  NoData Value=255
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 255,255,255,255
    2: 0,0,0,255
    ...
    254: 0,0,0,255
   255: 0,0,0,0
```

And in QGIS it's looks like:

[image]

Here is OMS and my rastr above. So white is transparent.
How can i remove `NoData Value` and Metadata tags from TIFF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use gdal_edit http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html

> -unsetnodata:
>
> ```
> (GDAL >= 2.1) Remove existing nodata values.
> ```

Usage:

```
gdal_edit 10000_EPSG2536_2.tif -unsetnodata
```

gdal_edit.py is a Python script and depending on your environment you may need to start if as `python gdal_edit.py`.

Comment: It's works, `NoData` had removed.  But image fully black now. It's possible to return white color on image?

Comment: Oh, you have a paletted image, it can make some difference. Do you have a test image to share? But actually color #255 is black in the palette `255: 0,0,0,0`. You should edit the palette to have `255: 255,255,255`.

Comment: I used solution from your another answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272847/how-to-change-raster-palette?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and it's works now my image looks nicely. Thanks man.